# How to set type hints for a function that can return multiple values?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I have a function that runs mysql select query and returns a list of values. However I am struggling with type hints.

Function:

```
def my_function(
    self,
    param1: List[str],
    param2: date,
    param3: int,
    param4: List[str],
    param5: List[int],
    param6: List[str],
    param7: int,
) -> List[Optional[str]]:
    """#TODO: Write docstring."""
    cnx = self.mysql
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = files(sql).joinpath("ready_batches.sql").read_text()

    param1_str = ",".join([f"'{lob}'" for lob in param1])
    param4_str = ",".join([f"'{clm_type}'" for clm_type in param4])
    param5_str = ",".join([f"{client_id}" for client_id in param5])
    param6_str = ",".join([f"{module_id}" for module_id in param6])

    with cnx, cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            query,
            {
                "lob": param1_str,
                "clm_type": param4_str,
                "client_id": param5_str,
                "param7": param7,
                "module_id": param6_str,
                "param3": param3,
                "param2": param2,
            },
        )

        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return [value for value, _ in result]
```

But mypy gives me the following problem in return list value:

> List comprehension has incompatible type List[Union[float, int,
> Decimal, str, bytes, date, timedelta, Set[str], None, Any]]; expected
> List[str]

I am certain the `value` will be a `str`. Hence I want to force the return type to `List[Optional(str)]`.

Comment: If all you know is it's a list, why `List[str]` to start with? `List[Any]`, perhaps?

Comment: List[Any] does solve the problem but I want to keep the type hint specific and tell the users the type of the elements.

Comment: The query fetches only one column and it is of str type.

Comment: If `List[str]` is the correct return type for the current implementation, [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the value?

Comment: Nothing about the return type of `cursor.fetchall` guarantees that all the values will be `str`s. You at least need to use `cast` to tell `mypy` about what you know outside the type system.

Comment: This code passes mypy check (tested on 1.4.1, with --strict flag). Could you share where self.mysql comes from? How is it typed?

Comment: `List[Any]` indicates the opposite of what you know your function will return. If you *know* the query returns exactly one string, then use `return [cast(str, value) for value, _ in result]`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I didn't think of it.

Comment: (Oops, my last comment referred to jonsharpe's first comment, not his later comment, which I saw but did not see it belonged to him.)

Comment: @chepner `cast(list[str], [value for value, _ in result])` is perhaps better, since only one call is needed instead of `n`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to "lie" as little as possible, but I guess a list of lies isn't significantly different from lying about a list, too :)

Comment: Oh, why `list[Optional[str]]`? That's not needed, if you are thinking that's needed for a possibly empty list. `[]` is still a list of (0) strings; `list[Optional[str]]` allows, for example, `[None]`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am certain the value will be a str.

In that case, cast your values to `str` so that mypy knows it.

> Hence I want to force the return type to List[Optional[str]].

`Optional[str]` means `None | str`. If you actually mean a list of zero or more strings, then `List[str]` is sufficient.